# Consecutive sequences of not cube-free numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples

Define a number to be cube-free if there is no prime factor that repeats more than once. Or, $n$ is cube-free if and only if $\frac{n}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}$ is square-free.

I've tested numbers up to $10,000,000$ without finding more than $4$ consecutive not cube-free numbers. Can this be proved to be a maximum or are there consecutive sequences with more than $4$ not cube-free numbers?

Comment: By "repeats more than once" I guess means occurs to power $3$ or more?

Comment: Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, one can show that there are sequences of cube-full numbers of any finite length.

Comment: Nice observation, that not only shows there are such numbers, but it gives an algorithm for constructing them.

Comment: This is not the usual definition of cubefull. The usual definition is that for all primes $p$, if $p$ divides $n$, then $p^3$ divides $n$. So, for example, $24$ is not cubefree, but neither is it cubefull.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Thank you! I changed the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
3^3 \mid 18035622\\
17^3 \mid 18035623\\
2^3 \mid 18035624\\
5^3 \mid 18035625\\
7^3 \mid 18035626
\end{align}
This is the smallest example of $5$ consecutive numbers that are not cubefree.

Also, you can now construct other examples from this one. For example, put $K=3^3\cdot 17^3\cdot2^3\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^3$, then we have:
\begin{align}
3^3 \mid K+18035622 \\ 
17^3 \mid K+18035623 \\ 
2^3 \mid K+18035624 \\ 
5^3 \mid K+18035625\\ 
7^3 \mid K+18035626
\end{align}

Now the hint given in comments gives you much better way to construct arbitrary long sequences of arbitrary powers (not just cubes) of multiples of arbitrary selected primes (for example). I suggest you look at Chinese Reminder Theorem and try to apply it to this problem.

EDIT: Whoops, I accidentally let the searching algorithm running over night, so here are couple more examples (always just first of five numbers): $100942496$, $133799496$, $146447622$, $156406624$, $185966872$, $\dots$.

Comment: +1 for "accidentally" giving more examples.